# Docker not able to identify Hyper-V on my system, no MobyLinux VM, how to create?

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

I have enabled Hyper-V on my system (and restarted). Then, I installed "Docker for Windows". Every time it gives me the same error when I start Docker.
[image]

I think, somehow, the MobyLinux VM is not created on my machine.
[image]

How do I configure one manually?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: Yes. A lot of times. Reinstalling, restarting, enabling/disabling Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

Docker was not able to create the VM on startup. This was because some of the powershell modules were not included in the path.

Check the path configured for Power shell modules `$env:psmodulepath`
Note: Use PowerShell as an administrator.

The path to "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules" must be present in the above list. If not, modify the below registry:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` to include this missing path.

Uninstall and reinstall Docker again.